# Wanna Learn PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have read many blog sites about powershell and I wanna learn practical skills in PowerShell.
Is there a website to read about what assignment to do or similiar?

Comment: Yes there is, it's called Google.

Comment: I already used google and I need to go to the next phase I'm talking about assignment or doin' project containing requirement specification and then implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Go through below articles which may help you lot

1. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4307.powershell-for-beginners.aspx
2. http://www.powershellpro.com/powershell-tutorial-introduction/

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to learn PowerShell and as a SharePoint developer or SharePoint administrator you should.

A good source for learning PowerShell is visiting the [microsoft virtual academy](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com). The have two course of learning PowerShell in general

- [getting-started-with-powershell-3-0-jump-start](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/getting-started-with-powershell-3-0-jump-start)
- [advanced-tools-scripting-with-powershell-3-0-jump-start](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/advanced-tools-scripting-with-powershell-3-0-jump-start)

Then there is MSDN for using PowerShell specific for Sharepoint

- [Windows PowerShell in the SharePoint Management Shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee536539%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

And ofcourse the sharepoint stackexchange site the is [full of solutions](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powershell) and cases using PowerShell in a SharePoint envirionment.

This list can go on and on but i think for the rest its best to use a Search engine of youre choice.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid, you will not get the required information on the blogs. Basically these kind of stuff you get from courses or from books.
here are few simple assignments related blogs:
[Link 1](http://pkaddala.blogspot.com/2010/11/lab-1-working-with-powershell-scripts.html)
[link 2](http://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2011/09/07/my-sharepoint-2010-powershell-tutorial-for-sharepoint-200-developers/)